# System Administrators not able to view records

Tags: administration, sharing, admin

We have installed a managed package in one our clients professional org
He reported that two Administrators are not able to see the data of each other.
only what they post.
Tried to see if it was a sharing rights issue, does not look like it.

Comment: Make sure when they click on the tab that they actually click on GO (or change the list view). If they are looking at the recent items it may not be present there if they never viewed the record. Have one give the other the URL of the record and see if they can see it.

Comment: Are they using the standard System Administrator profile, or a cloned version of it?

Answer (score 2):

It does look like a sharing setting issue to me.
Generally System admins have Modify All Data permission due to which they see all the data in the org. You could check this permission.
If this is not what you want to do,check the OWD of the concerned object.
If it is not public then that is your root cause.
When the OWD is private the users see only their own records and the records shared with them.

Comment: I have checked the OWD of the object involved it is public read/write